# Replacing text strings MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I've recently moved to a different platform for my personal website, and I've run into a problem where the previous encoding of characters such as `"`, `""`, and `'` are now recoded strangely as:

```
&amp;#8220;
&amp;#8221;
&amp;#8217;
â€™
&#039;
```

I've seen this before, and last time, I went through manually and updated each article. This time, however, I'd like to take a more pragmatic approach by updating the database.

How would I go about replacing all occurences of these strings with their correct character?

I'm thinking that it would be somehting like:

```
SELECT REPLACE('&#039;',''')
```

But do I need to be cautious and include escape characters like `\`? Also, how would I perform this type of replacement across the entire database?

Note: I'll be using phpMyAdmin to perform these replacements, so I'm hoping that it's just a matter of typing a series of commands into the "SQL" tab. Although, I do have access to the MySQL server from the command line if it's necessary.

**Update:**

More about the structure:

- The table name is "field_data_comment_body"
- The field name is "comment_body_value"
- The field in question is of type "longtext"

I've tried running Johan's recommendation, but it returns 0 Affected rows:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION FixEncoding(input longtext) RETURNS longtext
BEGIN
  DECLARE output longtext;

  SET output = input;   
  SET output = REPLACE(output,'&#039;','\'');
  SET output = REPLACE(output,'&amp;#8217;','\'');
  SET output = REPLACE(output,'&amp;#8221; ','"');
  SET output = REPLACE(output,'&amp;#8220;','"');
  SET output = REPLACE(output,'â€™','\'');

  RETURN output;
END $$

DELIMITER ;

UPDATE field_data_comment_body SET comment_body_value = FixEncoding(comment_body_value) WHERE entity_id <> 0;
```

Update: It's not a translation error as this returns 63 rows:

```
SELECT  `comment_body_value` 
FROM  `field_data_comment_body` 
WHERE  `comment_body_value` LIKE  '%&amp;#039;%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: How many rows does a `select count(*) as rowcount from field_data_comment_body WHERE entity_id <> 0;` return?

Comment: 63 rows. I think I got it sorted with: `update field_data_comment_body set comment_body_value = replace(comment_body_value,'&amp;#039;','\'');` Although it's not clear why your function didn't work, perhaps something to do with the field type?

Comment: It works with varchar, not sure 'bout longtext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL characters can be escaped by using `\`.

I'd write a function to do the replacing for you and than do an update, something like this.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION FixEncoding(input varchar) RETURNS varchar
BEGIN
  DECLARE output varchar;

  SET output = input;   
  SET output = REPLACE(output,'&#039;','\'');
  SET output = REPLACE(output, .....
  .....

  RETURN output;
END $$

DELIMITER ;

UPDATE table1 SET column1 = FixEncoding(Column1) WHERE id <> 0;
```

If this doesn't work then you might be suffering from translation issue between the database and the presentation layer.
Make a **backup** of your database
and change the encoding of your table(s) by using:

```
ALTER TABLE `test`.`test` CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci;
```

Comment: I've tried running an adaptation of the code you provided, but it seems that it has no effect on the rows.

Comment: In that case you are suffering from an translation issue between the database and the presentation layer, try to change the encoding of the database to latin1.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the case, the query that I've updated my question with displays the effected rows as expected

Comment: While this function didn't work for longtext, it still led me to my answer +1 +accept, thanks Johan!